# Mininet: iperf fails + can't add flows in user-space switch

Tags: mininet

I am new to mininet and SDN. Following is an issue I came across while exploring iperf command.

1) Set up a topology with three hosts and a user-space switch with following command:

```
$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --controller remote --switch user
```

2) No flow routes have been added.

3) Run a reference controller (POX) with following command:

```
$ controller ptcp:
```

4) iperf testing with following command:

```
mininet> iperf (on mininet console)
```

**Error #1:** `iperf` testing fails because flow routes are not defined. This is followed by a complete cleanup.

5) To fix this, I tried to add flow route with following command:

```
$ ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 in_port=1,actions=output:2
```

**Error #2:** I get following error message:

```
ovs-ofctl: s1 is not a bridge or a socket
```

Can anyone tell me what is my mistake? How can I fix this?

Reference: https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Learn-Development-Tools

Comment: any updates on this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `controller ptcp:6633`

If that doesn't work let me know what the output is.

I fell good about that controller command. Go to pox directory and try this:

`./pox.py forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub`

I assumed that you have pox already installed if you dont follow either of the instructions here:

1. This uses presetup VM: http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/pox/
2. Directly cloning it:

   $ git clone http://github.com/noxrepo/pox 
   $ cd pox

I hope it helps. Let me know if you need more help.

Some usefull resources: https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-InstallingPOX

Comment: 1) controller ptcp:6633 didn't help me. I got same errors again. iperf command does a complete clean up and adding routes fails. 2) POX is pre installed. 3) ./pox.py forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub fails too, I get this message: POX 0.2.0 (carp) / Copyright 2011-2013 James McCauley, et al.
Module not found: forwarding_12_hub. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Are you sure it is `forwarding_12_hub`. Cause the command says `forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. I had used forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub but it failed.

Comment: Could you provide the list of files in `/pox/pox/forwarding`. In my case the dir is `/home/ubuntu/pox/pox/forwarding`.

Comment: I tried UDP iperf between two hosts in mininet. but I am getting more than one packet in messgaes? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that based on user account privilege you may need to use `sudo` before the command. So if something doesn't work try it with sudo as well.

Have a look at following output.
let me know what part is different.

```
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/pox[14:38] (eel)$ ls 
debug-pox.py@  LICENSE  pox/     README     tests/
ext/           NOTICE   pox.py*  setup.cfg  tools/
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/pox[14:38] (eel)$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/pox
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/pox[14:38] (eel)$ git remote -v
origin  http://github.com/noxrepo/pox (fetch)
origin  http://github.com/noxrepo/pox (push)
ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~/pox[14:38] (eel)$ ./pox.py forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub
POX 0.5.0 (eel) / Copyright 2011-2014 James McCauley, et al.
INFO:core:POX 0.5.0 (eel) is up.
```

Comment: 1) with or without sudo, I get same error. 2) I see same files under pox folder.3) When I type ./pox.py forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub, I get this error:POX 0.2.0 (carp) / Copyright 2011-2013 James McCauley, et al.
Module not found: forwarding.tutorial_l2_hub

Answer (score 0):

Use `xterm h1` then call `iperf -s` or `iprf -c`.

Comment: I tried UDP iperf between two hosts in mininet. but the controller is getting more than one packet in messgaes? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please ask a new question

Comment: Asking questions is a better way to get audience to your question. Comments like these will eventually be a history. StackOverflow review team cleans up such comments periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Running iperf by itself in the topology in the tutorial attempts to run the test between h1 and h3. You need to create the flow entries between those two hosts:

> dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 in_port=3,idle_timeout=120,actions=output:1
>
> dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 in_port=1,idle_timeout=120,actions=output:3

Change the timeouts from 120 to something higher if you want. iperf should run just fine after this.

Comment: I tried UDP iperf between two hosts in mininet. but the controller is getting more than one packet in messgaes? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also got

> ovs-ofctl: s1 is not a bridge or a socket

It disappeared when I executed

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```